# How to Filter Locations Based on A specific location and a direction

Tags: android, augmented-reality, android-sensors, android-location

I'm trying to implement a small part of **AR**, The purpose is to filter locations based on My Location and A direction (North by example) :

I know that to know Direction i need to use [Sensor type Orientation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_ORIENTATION)

[Memory Conception](http://postimg.org/image/ksfgfnr5h/)

So can someone help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can get the distance and angle to a point by using Location.distanceTo().  So you'd want to loop through all the points, get the distance and bearing.  If the object is close enough and the bearing is within the angle you want, then you treat it as a good point and display it.  If it isn't, you skip it.